# Error in system.file() while trying to knit in RMarkdown using Rstudio

Tags: r-markdown

I am unable to knit thesis and articles since I have updated Rstudio and some of the packages under a project (git version). I keep getting the following error. I have tried solving the issue reinstalling the packages, R, Rtools and Rstudios. However, the error still persists.

*Error in system.file(..., package = package, mustWork = mustWork) :
no file found
Calls:  ... lua_filter ->  -> pkg_file -> system.file
Execution halted*

Any assistance with the issue would be great. Thanks

Comment: Do you knit to pdf? You have problems with knitting of every file?

Comment: I would knit to pdf/ doc. However, I am having problem with knitting every file.